# SQL - AND gets ignored after Like STATEMENT

Tags: php, sql, sql-like

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carBrand LIKE '%alfa%' OR carModel LIKE '%alfa%'
```

Everything i put after that sentence just gets ignored.
I was hoping to be able to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE carBrand LIKE '%alfa%'
OR carModel LIKE '%alfa%' AND carType = 'truck'
```

This just gets ignored.

```
AND carType = 'truck'
```

Why?

Comment: First thing I would try is `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (carBrand LIKE '%alfa%') OR (carModel LIKE '%alfa%' AND carType = 'truck')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
WHERE (carBrand LIKE '%alfa%' OR carModel LIKE '%alfa%')
AND carType = 'truck'
```

`AND` binds stronger than `OR`. It's called *Operator Precedence*. Without parentheses your query compiles to

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
WHERE carBrand LIKE '%alfa%' 
OR (carModel LIKE '%alfa%' AND carType = 'truck')
```